# How to turn ctree nodes into a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, nodes, ctree

I'll explain my problem using an example with the iris table. Let's say I want to create a tree between sepal width and species. For this I will use this code:

```
ctree(Species~Sepal.Width,data=iris)->a
plot(a,type="simple")
```

The problem is that, if I want to do a data frame, for example counting the quantity of cases in each node (from 0 to 2.9; 2.9 to 3.3, etc), the only way I've found to do this is by creating a new vector manually and then using the `dcast` or `table` function.

The problem with this solution is that if I had a bigger tree result, it could be quite difficult. Do you know any other solution for this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the party structure created by `ctree` has that information stored in it. Using your example, `a[1]$fitted[,1]` has which leaf each point ended up in. So you can get the number of points at each leaf with:

```
table(a[1]$fitted[,1])
 3  4  5 
57 56 37
```

If you are trying to see the rules that go with the leaf numbers, you can use:

```
partykit:::.list.rules.party(a)
                                        3 
"Sepal.Width <= 3.3 & Sepal.Width <= 2.9" 
                                        4 
 "Sepal.Width <= 3.3 & Sepal.Width > 2.9" 
                                        5 
                      "Sepal.Width > 3.3"
```

Comment: Hello, if I execute a[1]$fitted[,1], I obtain this error:Error in a[1] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: When I execute your code above, then execute my code, I get no error. when I run `class(a)` I get `[1] "constparty" "party"`  What do you get?

Comment: I get     [1] "BinaryTree"
attr(,"package")
[1] "party